# Response Email Activity Images in CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, jscript

How can I preserve images in a response to an email activity? 
The images in the email show when viewed in CRM - they are added as attachments. When I click the 'respond' button, write a response, and send the response the images are stripped from the email and are not attached to the email. 

I have been trying all sorts of things with JScript . 
I would rather not have to write anything other than JScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can access the attachments here: 
 https:{org. URL}/xrmServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/EmailSet(guid'3848cb4d-673f-e211-b9af-005056bd0001')/email_activity_mime_attachment


guid is the guid of the email. 
The image is stored in d:Body as Base64. 
Now all I need to do is rewrite img for each inline image with src="data:image/png;base64,theverylongstring... 
All inline images will be preserved in the response as Base64.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with javascript. I don't know what you tried but this can be done. I.e. catch the send event of your form and create the attachment with Javascript.

Other options are:

- You could use a workflow to attach the note of the parent email to
  the response. But then you will be forced to save your email wait a
  little while (execution of the workflow) and then send the email.
- Write plug-in code (but you won't use anything else but Javascript

Javascript to delete attachment:

```
function deleteAttachments(){ 
    var notesId = {GUID of notes};
    var objNotes = new Object();
    objNotes.DocumentBody = null;
    objNotes.FileName = null;
    objNotes.FileSize = null;
    objNotes.IsDocument = false;
    updateRecord(notesId, objNotes, “AnnotationSet”);
}

function updateRecord(id, entityObject, odataSetName) {
        var jsonEntity = window.JSON.stringify(entityObject);
        var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();
        var ODATA_ENDPOINT = “/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc”;
        var updateRecordReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var ODataPath = serverUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT;
        updateRecordReq.open(‘POST’, ODataPath + “/” + odataSetName + “(guid’” + id + “‘)”, false);
        updateRecordReq.setRequestHeader(“Accept”, “application/json”);
        updateRecordReq.setRequestHeader(“Content-Type”, “application/json; charset=utf-8″);
        updateRecordReq.setRequestHeader(“X-HTTP-Method”, “MERGE”);
        updateRecordReq.send(jsonEntity);
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a good option. How do I access the attachment of the parent email from Javascript or from a workflow? I have tried to access the attachments of the parent email without success. The only way I have found is to get the URL directly from the form, but it has a timestamp and this method does not seem correct.

Comment: You have to find out how the attachment gets saved but i reckon its like a note with an attachment. edited my answer

Comment: I'll post if I find out how an attachment gets saved. At the moment I can only access the name and other meta data of the attachment through OrganizationalData. I cannot add a dynamic value attachment to a workflow, so workflows seem to be out of the equation.